# Cannot find table element from div element in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select a `table` values from `div` element using `selenium`,

When I inspect the element, I could see the element contains the `table` but I cannot find it while viewing the source code (which is happening while trying to access through selenium).

**During Inspect:**

[image]

Below is the code I tried,

```
totals = driver.find_element_by_id("totals")#gets the totals div element. Only one is there
labels=totals.find_elements_by_class_name("hasLabel")#should get the table rows, but it was empty
print(len(labels))#returned 0
```

But, It was empty (as I saw in the source code). I need to export those values in a file as part of automation

Is there any other way I can extract those due values?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation seems to be near perfect. As per the HTML within **During Inspect** snapshot which you have shared, The element with text as **Taxes Due** is highlighted.

---

While within the **While viewing the source code** snapshot which you have extracted through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), possibly the *Page Source* was pulled out  even before the child elements have completely rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes):

[image: source code]

Hence the child elements within `<div id='totals'></div>` are not present withi the *Page Source*.

---

The relevant HTML in text format would have help to construct a canonical answer. However, to get the total number of `<tr>` elements you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody//tr[@class='hasLabel'][./td[@class='label']]")))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand. Could you please elaborate?. Where did I highlighted _Payment Type_? I have updated the screenshot of my inspect now for a better clarity. Kindly check.

Comment: @Praveen Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.