# A tough scraping case using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So I am trying to scrape a [webs table](https://www.euroinvestor.dk/markeder/aktier/sverige/omx-stockholm-30/21) using selenium trying to extract the table with xpath:

previously I tried to look for the table class however no tables where found , so I decided to look for the div element.

```
xpath="//div[@class='table-scroller ScrollableTable__table-scroller QuoteHistoryTable__table__scroller QuoteHistoryTable__QuoteHistoryTable__table__scroller']"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html5lib")

table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-scroller ScrollableTable__table-scroller QuoteHistoryTable__table__scroller QuoteHistoryTable__QuoteHistoryTable__table__scroller'})
df = pd.read_html(str(table), flavor='html5lib', header=0, thousands='.', decimal=',')
print(df[0])
```

The issue I am having is that I am printing only the headers and a first row of values full of `nans`:

[image]

Why am I not getting the values of the table? What it makes it so tough to scrape this content?

**EDIT:** @DebanjanB was able to provide a nice answer however I am unable to replicate the output, whats the reason behind this?

Comment: BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html5lib") Anything named html_source?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960297/struggling-to-scrap-a-table-using-selenium/63961567#63961567 you had a similar question. Just switch to css selector.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Thank you for the idea but changing the XPATH to CSS, the issue still exists, where I generate the df with the same row of nans, I decided to post a different question because I think in this case the issue is different as I access the frame but not the values inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the page requests, you might notice an endpoint offering you just the right info as JSON:

https://api.euroinvestor.dk/indices/21/instruments

You can use `pandas` to read straight from the URL (you don't even need Selenium):

```py
instruments = pd.read_json('https://api.euroinvestor.dk/indices/21/instruments')
```

Be sure to look at the API usage terms (especially any rate limits); you might get blocked otherwise.

Comment: where can I  find the  API usage terms ?

Comment: @JamesHudson81 I suspect it's somewhere at the bottom of https://www.euroinvestor.dk/, but I do not speak Danish: Generelle handelsbetingelser | Cookie-og Privatlivspolitik | Cookiedeklaration | Vilkår

Answer (score 0):

To extract the contents from the **OMX Stockholm 30** `<table>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='OMX Stockholm 30']//following::div[2]//table"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  VÆRDIPAPIR
  KURS
  ÆNDRING I %
  ÆNDRING
  VOLUME
  BUD
  UDBUD
  OPDATERET
  ABB LTD
  229,60
  0,13%
  0,30
  1.953.199 229,20 229,30 18.09.2020
  ALFA LAVAL AB
  210,50
  1,20%
  2,50
  1.513.953 210,30 210,40 18.09.2020
  ASSA ABLOY AB SER. B
  216,00
  1,55%
  3,30
  3.250.421 216,20 216,40 18.09.2020
  ASTRAZENECA PLC
  995,10
  0,56%
  5,50
  507.005 994,70 995,00 18.09.2020
  ATLAS COPCO AB SER. A
  425,60
  1,89%
  7,90
  2.313.361 425,80 426,10 18.09.2020
  ATLAS COPCO AB SER. B
  376,60
  2,78%
  10,20
  971.096 376,60 376,90 18.09.2020
  AUTOLIV INC. SDB
  655,00
  -1,18%
  -7,80
  279.485 656,80 657,40 18.09.2020
  BOLIDEN AB
  275,80
  1,03%
  2,80
  2.450.311 276,60 276,80 18.09.2020
  ELECTROLUX, AB SER. B
  194,60
  0,34%
  0,65
  1.381.656 195,00 195,10 18.09.2020
  ERICSSON, TELEFONAB. L M SER.
  98,26
  1,30%
  1,26
  17.811.892 98,12 98,16 18.09.2020
  ESSITY AB SER. B
  306,40
  -0,20%
  -0,60
  1.795.692 306,20 306,40 18.09.2020
  GETINGE AB SER. B
  188,10
  1,65%
  3,05
  864.843 188,05 188,15 18.09.2020
  HENNES & MAURITZ AB, H &#3
  157,85
  -1,68%
  -2,70
  5.188.908 157,85 157,90 18.09.2020
  HEXAGON AB SER. B
  677,20
  0,06%
  0,40
  776.831 676,20 676,80 18.09.2020
  INVESTOR AB SER. B
  584,60
  1,53%
  8,80
  1.681.508 585,00 585,20 18.09.2020
  KINNEVIK AB SER. B
  336,95
  3,34%
  10,90
  1.118.689 336,35 336,55 18.09.2020
  NORDEA BANK ABP
  68,37
  -1,85%
  -1,29
  11.846.193 68,45 68,48 18.09.2020
  SANDVIK AB
  185,10
  1,54%
  2,80
  3.874.524 185,00 185,10 18.09.2020
  SECURITAS AB SER. B
  140,00
  -0,53%
  -0,75
  1.545.060 140,20 140,35 18.09.2020
  SKANDINAVISKA ENSKILDA BANKEN
  81,38
  -3,46%
  -2,92
  10.968.672 81,38 81,42 18.09.2020
  ```

---

### Update

As you mentioned within your comments *...either getting a timeout or I am only able to get the headers...* that effectively implies our locators are correct and the issue is with rendering and in that case you can [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get('https://www.euroinvestor.dk/markeder/aktier/sverige/omx-stockholm-30/21')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='OMX Stockholm 30']"))))
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='OMX Stockholm 30']//following::div[2]//table"))).text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response however I am unable to replicate the output. I am either getting a timeout or I am only able to get the headers, I also do not understand the path reference stated, is this also angular ?

Comment: @JamesHudson81 Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.