# Python selenium send_keys brokes text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-exception

I use python + selenium to add some text into the text area (in DOM it is a DIV tag).

For example, I have the following text:

```
EVERY SINGLE picture or video you will publish with
```

after using `send_keys()` function the text inside textarea became following:

```
EVERY SINGLE ice o ideo o ill blih ih
```

Code snippet:

```py
message = 'EVERY SINGLE picture or video you will publish with'
reply_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Message Body"]'))
                                )
reply_input.clear()
reply_input.click()
reply_input.send_keys(message)
```

The problem is, that the issue not stable to reproduce, it appears from time to time.

Does anyone know how to solve such a problem?

Comment: You can try workaround like `for char in "EVERY SINGLE picture or video you will publish with": reply_input.send_keys(char); time.sleep(0.1)`

Comment: Looks like this WA is working.

Answer (score -1):

[`presence_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) doesn't ensures that the element is **interactable**. Instead you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
message = 'EVERY SINGLE picture or video you will publish with'
reply_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label="Message Body"]")))
reply_input.click()
reply_input.clear()
reply_input.send_keys(message)
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How do you use EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, “myDynamicElement”)) except to specify class not ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803)
- [Struggling to scrape a table using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960297/struggling-to-scrape-a-table-using-selenium/63962667#63962667)